# Signing with maven-gpg-plugin fails with "No secret key"

Tags: maven, gnupg, signing

I am trying to deploy my project to maven central. Doing so requires me to sign my artifact, which I am trying to do with the maven-gpg-plugin. I'm following https://central.sonatype.org/publish/requirements/gpg/ but I seem to have made a mistake along the way that I am unable to notice.

I have added the plugin to my pom.xml like so:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sign</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I have created the keys using the command

```
gpg --default-new-key-algo rsa4096 --gen-key
```

I entered my name and email in the interactive dialogue and got my key. I can check it with

```
gpg --list-secret-keys
```

and get:

```
------------------------------------------------
sec   rsa4096 2022-01-05 [SC] [expires: 2024-01-05]
      F7F006240EC337B8ACC24C6E5EF1093EC9E45150
uid        [ ultimate ] My_Name <My_Email>
```

I have created a settings.xml in my .m2 directory containing the passphrase that GPG4Win asked me during the creation with the tag

```
<gpg.passphrase>
```

In my .gnupg directory I created a gpg.conf file containing

```
default-key F7F006240EC337B8ACC24C6E5EF1093EC9E45150
```

When I run maven clean deploy I get

```
gpg: skipped "F7F006240EC337B8ACC24C6E5EF1093EC9E45150": No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

When I delete the gpg.conf file I get

```
gpg: no default secret key: No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

When I pass the key name with the maven command like so

```
mvn clean deploy -Dgpg.keyname=F7F006240EC337B8ACC24C6E5EF1093EC9E45150
```

it also fails with

```
gpg: skipped "F7F006240EC337B8ACC24C6E5EF1093EC9E45150": No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

How do I get maven to find the key I generated?

Comment: You have to use the key id and not the full key..use the last 8 characters `C9E45150` (If I correctly remember)... or check if you can show the key id via GUI...

Comment: Thank you @khmarbaise. I have tried with command "mvn clean deploy -Dgpg.keyname=0xC9E45150" but still nothing it. skips the key and says "no secret key". When I do "gpg --edit-key 0xC9E45150" it lists the key and says that there is a secret key.

Comment: I have managed to fix the problem by running the mvn command in cmd, not git bash. For some reason, that worked.

Comment: Yeah Git bash behaves different...